# Stop Javascript function when scroll on div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a iframe Vimeo video as a header for my website and I'm using a Javascript that lets the page scroll down to a certain div after a certain amount of time.

So when the video is finished, the page automatically scrolls down to the next div.

But when you don't finish watching the video and already scroll down, it's annoying when the page automatically scrolls up again.

What can I do? Is there a different solution for this? Or can I maybe stop the Javascript function when the page reaches this div it's supposed to go to?

I hope I'm being clear.

This is the script

```
$(window).load(function () {
//normally you'd wait for document.ready, but you'd likely to want to wait
//for images to load in case they reflow the page
$('body').delay(36000) //wait 5 seconds
    .animate({
        //animate jQuery's custom "scrollTop" style
        //grab the value as the offset of #second from the top of the page
        'scrollTop': $('.first-block').offset().top
    }, 1000); //animate over 300ms, change this to however long you want it to animate for
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a scroll listener where you can stop the timeout function to be executed by calling `clearTimeout()` as stated here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

```
var animation = setTimeout(function() {
   $('body').animate({
       'scrollTop': $('.first-block').offset().top
    }, 1000);
}, 36000);

$(window).scroll(function() {
   clearTimeout(animation); // stop the timeout to be executed
   $(window).off('scroll'); // we don't need this handler any more so unregister
});
```

As a bonus you can disable the scroll listener via `off()`, if you don't have any more scroll scripts active like in your question. So that the scroll function and `clearTimeout()` has not to be called again. See also: https://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 0):

Assign the delay via `setTimeout` to a variable.

```
var delay = setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('body').animate({
        'scrollTop': $('.first-block').offset().top
    }, 1000);
}, 36000);
```

If the user scrolls you can clear the timeout previously assigned via `clearTimeout`:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    clearTimeout(delay);
});
```